# Union-ing lists created in locals

Tags: terraform

I'm trying to create a list of resources to create which will be passed to a module. When trying this:

```
variable "number_of_nodes" {
  default = 5
}

locals {
  nodes_to_create      = [for node in range(var.number_of_nodes) : ["k8s-node-${node}", false]]
  controller_to_create = [["k8s-ctl", true]]
  vms_to_create = setunion(nodes_to_create, controller_to_create)
}

output "test1" {
  value = local.controller_to_create
}

output "test2" {
  value = local.nodes_to_create
}

output "test3" {
  value = local.vms_to_create
}
```

I get the following errors:

```
Error: Invalid reference
│
│   on main.tf line 8, in locals:
│    8:   vms_to_create = setunion(nodes_to_create, controller_to_create)
│
│ A reference to a resource type must be followed by at least one attribute access, specifying the resource name.
```

and

```
Error: Invalid reference
│
│   on main.tf line 8, in locals:
│    8:   vms_to_create = setunion(nodes_to_create, controller_to_create)
│
│ A reference to a resource type must be followed by at least one attribute access, specifying the resource name.
```

I've tried referencing the lists using *locals.nodes_to_create* or *locals.controller_to_create* to no avail. How can I combine these two lists, so I can pass a single list to my module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still need to use the `local` specifier in the variable themselves:

```
locals {
  nodes_to_create      = [for node in range(var.number_of_nodes) : ["k8s-node-${node}", false]]
  controller_to_create = [["k8s-ctl", true]]
  vms_to_create = setunion(local.nodes_to_create, local.controller_to_create)
}
```

Comment: Stupidly tried "locals" instead of "local". Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Since these are local variables, you need to tell terraform you are referencing them, so instead of:

```
vms_to_create = setunion(nodes_to_create, controller_to_create)
```

You need:

```
vms_to_create = setunion(local.nodes_to_create, local.controller_to_create)
```